# WSDL2Java: missing complex element type generates java.lang.Object argument types

Tags: jaxb, spring-ws, wsdl2java, wsimport

I am trying to import this WSDL: https://gateway.monster.com:8443/bgwBroker

Among others, it includes this XSD: http://schemas.monster.com/current/xsd/Query.xsd, which contains this snippet:

```xml
<xsd:element name="Query">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Target" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="SubTarget" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="ResumeRestriction" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="ReturnRestriction" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     ...
   </xsd:element>
   <xsd:element name="SelectBy" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     ...
   </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
...
<xsd:element name="ResumeRestriction">
  ... 
</xsd:element>
```

As you can see, complex type `ResumeRestriction` and its fields is defined at the bottom, but referenced inside Query. There is a reference missing here. `ReturnRestriction` and `SelectBy` are defined inline and are generated correctly.

Using WSDL2Java, this generates the following annotated classes:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "target",
    "subTarget",
    "resumeRestriction",
    "returnRestriction",
    "selectBy"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Query")
public class Query {

    @XmlElement(name = "Target", required = true)
    protected String target;
    @XmlElement(name = "SubTarget")
    protected String subTarget;
    @XmlElement(name = "ResumeRestriction")
    protected Object resumeRestriction;
    ...
    public void setResumeRestriction(Object value) {
        this.resumeRestriction = value;
    }
}
```

Making `resumeRestriction` of type `Object` instead of the right type.

If do have a generated version of `ResumeRestriction` just fine. They are just not being tied together:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "storeRenderedTextResume",
    "doNotRenderSid",
    "activeOnBoard"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ResumeRestriction")
public class ResumeRestriction {
...
}
```

If I now create a request using Spring Web Services, I cannot use the `ResumeRestriction` class, which I need in my request to set a specific flag.

```java
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

        Query query = objectFactory.createQuery();
        query.setTarget("JobSeekers");

        ResumeRestriction resumeRestriction = objectFactory.createResumeRestriction();
        resumeRestriction.setStoreRenderedTextResume(true);
        query.setResumeRestriction(resumeRestriction);

        getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive("https://gateway.monster.com:8443/bgwBroker", query);
```

This will throw the following error:

```
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: Instance of "com.monster.schemas.monster.ResumeRestriction" is substituting "java.lang.Object", but "com.monster.schemas.monster.ResumeRestriction" is bound to an anonymous type.]
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

I obviously cannot change the WSDL or XSD, as I pull those in remotely. Is this is a bug on their side and if so, can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the class reference in JAXB bindings file:

```
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
>

   <jxb:bindings >
       <jxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="3000"/>
   </jxb:bindings>

   <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://schemas.monster.com/current/xsd/Query.xsd">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Query']//xs:element[@name='ResumeRestriction']">
                <jxb:class ref="com.monster.schemas.monster.ResumeRestriction"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```